# Fastest insert without duplication for small number of items

Tags: c++, performance, duplicates, collision-detection

I'm inserting integers into a container. Many of the integers are duplicate, in that case I want to insert just one. I do not expect more than 100 (typically just <10) items in container at the end.

Natural solution is to use [std::unordered_set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/) or [std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/). But still I have some questions:

- unordered_set is O(1) while set is O(log n), but for small number of elements may be set faster?
- I have really small number of elements so I do not really care about memory complexity. Is there some more specialized algorithm which would be even faster than unordered_set(i.e. hashmap)?

**Details & Background:** I use regular 3D grid to store objects in 3D engine. Some objects overlap more cells. When I check which objects overlaps with object A, I go over all cells overlapping with A and insert all objects in each cell

```
int findInCells( int n, int* cells, int* objects ){
    std::unordered_set<int> found;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){                                   // go over cells
        auto range = map.equal_range( cells[i] );             // list all objects in std::unordered_multimap<int,int> map;
        for(auto it = range.first; it != range.second; it++){ // 
            found.insert(it->second);
        }
    }
    int io=0;
    for(int o : found){ objects[io]=o; }
    return io;
}
```

I'm trying to make it not much slower than simpler version which does not care about duplicates.

```
int findInCellsNaive( int n, int* cells, int* objects ){
    // problem - what if we have same object in two different cells? we will insert it multiple times
    int io=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){                                    // go over cells
        auto range = map.equal_range( cells[i] );             // list all objects in std::unordered_multimap<int,int> map;
        for(auto it = range.first; it != range.second; it++){  // 
            outInds[io]=it->second;
            io++;
        }
    }
    return io;
}
```

An other solution I'm trying is to "paint" already inserted objects using additional boolean array with size of number of all objects.

```
bool* painted = new bool[NOBJECTS]; 
for(int i=0; i<NOBJECTS; i++){ painted[o]=true; };

inline int findInCellsPaint( int n, int* cells, int* objects ){
    int io=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){                                    // go over cells
        auto range = map.equal_range( cells[i] );             // list all objects in std::unordered_multimap<int,int> map;
        for(auto it = range.first; it != range.second; it++){  // 
            int o = it->second;
            if( painted[o] ){
                objects[io]=o;
                painted[o]=false;
                io++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<io; i++){ painted[objects[o]]=true; };
    return io;
}
```

Comment: For performance on small set, you have to measure "wrong" algo might be faster than the one with correct complexity (due to cache, ...). (`std::vector` with linear search might be faster for example).

Comment: *"unordered_set is (O(1)) while set is (O(n))"*, `O(log(n))` for `set`.

Comment: An possible alternative: store all with duplicates, then `std::sort`, and `std::unique`.

Comment: best would be to perform some benchmark on both version (a lot can depend on certain CPU, compiler setting and so on). I would go for unordered_set and maybe check std::vector with search. std::vector could be fast because of using cache

Comment: optimizations always depends on the data, if you say that you will have 10 to 100 items in the container and will check 10000000000 items, I would use a sorted vector or a implementation of a eytzinger vector.

Comment: `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map` *are* hashmaps. `std::set` insert is `O(log(n))`. If you have a bunch of unsorted elements, there is obviously no way to get it faster than `O(n)`.

Comment: What is the range and distribution of the integers?